# how to debug small programs in python

Tags: python, palindrome

I have problem with my code. I have a sentence, and this sentence has palindromic words with 5 letters each one. The sentence is: `the level rotor is in the radar`. As you can see, the palindromic words are: level, rotor and radar. Firstly, I grouped the words in 5 letters like this: thele helev eleve level, and so on.

My code is something like this:

```py
test = "the level rotor is in the radar"
data = []

for i in range(len(test) - 5):
    data.append(test[i:i+6])
    print(data)

def siqpalindromics(pal):
    return pal == pal[::-1]

pal = "data"
anpal = siqpalindromics(pal)

if anpal:
    print("it is palindromic"), print(pal)
else:
    print("it isnt palindromic")
```

I want to print for example:

```
thele it isnt palindromic
helev it isnt palindromic
eleve it isnt palindromic
level it is palindromic
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use an IDE like PyCharm (which is free) to debug, via a GUI debugger. Here's how: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html

Comment: Please [edit] your title so it _summarizes the specific problem you are asking about_, and indent your code correctly since badly indented python code is invalid python code.

Comment: Are you trying specifically to find sequences of exactly 5 letters that are palindromic, regardless of word boundaries? Or something else?

Comment: In Python or any other language, take a look at https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: yes, I want to group in 5 words, and I am looking the palindromic words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to check whether each extracted word is a palindrome.

```py
def is_palindrome(s):
    return s == s[::-1]

data = "the level rotor is in the radar"
data = data.replace(' ', '')
words = []
word_length = 5
for i in range(len(data) - word_length + 1):
    words.append(data[i:i+word_length])

for word in words:
    if is_palindrome(word):
        print(f'{word} is palindromic')
    else:
        print(f'{word} is not palindromic')
```