# Recursive approach to triangle pattern printing

Tags: python, recursion

I have been learning concepts like recursion lately and tried attempting old programs in python that I solved using an iterative approach for example printing triangular patterns, for example:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

but the output I get is:

```
*****
****
*** 
**  
*   
None
```

```py
def itriangle(x):
    if x==0:
        return
    print("*",end="")
    itriangle(x-1)
def jtriangle(y):
    if y==0:
        return
    itriangle(y)
    print()
    jtriangle(y-1)
print(jtriangle(5))
```

this is the code I wrote,
Firstly I get this triangle inverted and secondly I get a "None" return as the last line.
How to fix this?

Edit: I have fixed the None that I was getting , that was just a typo on my side but now the problem (The main issue) is that I am getting an inverted triangle and dont know how to fix it. any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense to claim you wrote some code and then to ask people on StackOverflow "what the concept behind it is". That's not how programming works - you don't just get inspiration in the form of code and then try to divine what it means. This is a very standard example used in teaching recursion. What exactly is unclear about it to you? Have you tried stepping through it? Calling `jtriangle(5)` from with the `print` statement only serves to print the return value, which is always `None`.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180481/how-to-debug-small-programs-in-python#comment125822952_71180481)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion can be confusing. I use natural language to make sure I write recursive programs correctly. I can say:

> To print a triangle of size `n`, first print a triangle of size `n-1`, then print a line of size `n`.

Then convert it directly into code:

```
def triangle(n):
    if n==0:
        return
    triangle(n-1)
    print()
    line(n)
```

Note: names like `jtriangle` and `itriangle` don't convey the meaning well. They only serve to confuse you, and recursion is already confusing enough, so use meaningful names instead!

---

Another powerful technique I use when developing recursive programs (actually always, but it's especially helpful when using recursion): use bottom-up development! That is, make sure your lower-level functions really work and are free of bugs, *before* developing your upper-level functions.

In my example above, make sure the `line` function works well before writing code for the `triangle` function. If you have bugs in lower-level functions, recursion will mess you up, and it will be much harder to debug.

Answer (score 1):

On why you get `None` at the end: this is because the `print(jtriangle(5))` statement prints the return value of the `jtriangle(5)` function, which is `None` by default since there is no explicit `return` statement. The functions themselves handle all the necessary printing, so you don't need to print the result of the function call. You can simply call `jtriangle(5)` without `print`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your triangle to be upright you need to reconsider your logic. In the below example, the current recursion puts it's line data after the next recursion call. Since every call is coming before the line that called it, we essentially end up with the line data in reverse. Also, instead of printing in the function, we let all the data "build" and print it on final return.

```
def triangle(x):
    if not x: return ''
    return f'{triangle(x-1)}{"*"*x}\n'
    
print(triangle(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to arrange for the recursive function to just prepare the data for printing elsewhere. This makes the function more likely to be re-usable.

Thus, by creating a list of rows, we can just reverse the list for the desired effect.

```
def triangle(n): # 1 -> N
    rows = []
    def _triangle(x):
        nonlocal rows
        if x <= 0:
            return
        rows.append("*" * x)
        _triangle(x-1)
    _triangle(n)
    return rows


N = 10
rows = triangle(N)
print(*rows[::-1], sep="\n")
print()
print(*rows, sep="\n")
```

**Output:**

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********

**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Answer (score 0):

A *recursive process* has two phases:

- **calling phase** (going toward the base case), and
- **returning phase** (coming back from the base case).

A command put *before the recursive call* is executed on the way down (**calling phase**) and a command put *after the recursive call* is executed on the way up (**returning phase**).

```py
def downward(n):
    if n <= 0: return
    print(n * '*')     # executed before recursive call
    downward(n-1) 

def upward(n):
    if n <= 0: return
    upward(n-1)
    print(n * '*')     # executed after recursive call
```

Examples:

```py
>>> downward(5)
*****
****
***
**
*
>>> upward(5)
*
**
***
****
*****
>>>
```